# Insert records in the same order without allowing duplicates

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE tblTesting
(
  col1 INT NOT NULL ,
  col2 VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT  tblTesting
VALUES  ( 4, 'test' ),
        ( 1, 'test2' ),
        ( 4, 'test' ),
        ( 1, 'test2' );

col1        col2
----------- -----------
4           test
1           test2
4           test
1           test2
```

Here it is allowing duplicates.But it shouldn't and need to insert the records in the same order. How can i achieve it?

Comment: There are no duplicates here. And SQL tables don't have any intrinsic order. Can you share an example of the result you're trying to get to make this question a bit clearer?

Comment: Tables have no order. You specify the order when you select. Otherwise the optimizer will return rows without imposing any order. This will mix up rows in multi-core machines or simply because one operator changed the order

Comment: While inserting it should be like this as shown below:-  col1        col2
----------- --------------------------------------------------
4           test
1           test2  But it should not allow like this as shown below:- col1        col2
----------- --------------------------------------------------
4           test
1           test2
4           test
1           test2

Comment: Please use the [edit option](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41975700/edit) to put additional information directly into the question (much better formatting abilities!). And once again: **There is no implicit order**

Comment: You can add a [unique constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or a [compound key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189039.aspx) to prevent your table from holding duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have stated, the order of SQL tables doesn't matter, as the data is retrieved according to your statements, indexes, etc.  If you need your data to be returned in a specific order you simply tell SQL to return it in that order with the `order by` clause:

```
select col1
      ,col2
from tblTesting
order by col1
        ,col2
```

If you don't want to allow duplicates on certain values, you can add constraints that require a unique value or set of values, per the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396